# Setting Yamaha MG10XUF mixing console

Tags: mixing, homerecording

I am trying to set up my MG19XUF mixing console as the usb sound card directly connected to computer to record music in Audacity and then to listen my recordings (as well as any audio played from the MAC) directly from the mixing console.

As I understood, any output signal came from the computer goes directly to the port 9/10 of the console. So the fader of this channel controlls output for the monitors (connected to the monitors out) as well as the headset. What mode of the red button (to mon/ to st) of the channel 9/10 as well as Line/USB swith should be used adequately? For example, while playing any audio form mac, I can hear the output in the headset only with the activated USB switch (down). At the same time, I can't understand what the red switch (to mon/ to st) does..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about music practise or theory, it is a 'how do I operate my equipment?' question, for which there is a manual - https://jp.yamaha.com/files/download/other_assets/9/1149669/mg10xuf_en_om_a0.pdf

Comment: well, you are right! I just thought that there might be here someone who had been worked with this equipment and knew the quick tip (believe me, there is nothing about it in manual, I have already cheched!) Cheers!

Comment: Yes, there is. Page 16.

Comment: @Tetsujin I'd like to point out that questions about "usage of specific music software or hardware" are on topic. The issue with this question is that OP asks us to read the manual to them.

Comment: @user1079505 - Yes, I'm completely aware that 'usage' is on topic. RTFM questions don't qualify.